# Project Euler #8 Issue

Tags: java, project

I'm doing question 8 on project Euler, and having some issues. It says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
>       at main.main(main.java:19)

when I try and run it with the required 13 digits, it gets to '0420752963450' which is the last 13 digit string, and crashes with the above error.

I know what the error means and where it is coming from, but I can't seem to fix it.

So, my question is how to make this work? Where exactly am I going wrong? I've spent several hours trying to fix this.

```
public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String string = ("7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");
    char[] charAr = string.toCharArray();
    int x = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int y = 14;
    int product = 0;
    int tempx = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int times = 1;
    int newLargest = 0;
    while (tempx <= 999){
        tempx = x;
        times = 1;
        while (x < (y - 1)){
            System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1])));
            times = times * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1]));
            x++;
            i++;            
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(
           "X: " + x + "\t Times: " + times + "\t tempx: " + tempx);
        x = tempx;
        x++;
        y++;

        if (i == 1000){
            i = 0;
        }
        temp = product;
        product = times;
        //System.out.println(times);
        if (product > temp){
            newLargest = product;
            //System.out.println(newLargest);
        }
        //System.out.println(newLargest);
    }
    //System.out.println(newLargest);
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without checking the validity of your solution to Euler #8:

Modify the second while condition from:

```
while (x < (y - 1))
```

to:

```
while (x < (y - 1) && x < charAr.length+1)
```

in order to break when you're reaching the last cell of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add if-condition inside the while loop:

```
while (x < (y - 1)){
    if(x-1 >= charAr.length) break; // add this line
    System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1])));
    times = times * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1]));
    x++;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your algorithm, to be honest preventing the error is really easy but I have found out that you're over-complicating the task e.g why do you have to convert it to char array when you can easily access the numbers using the "String.charAt()" method. Also even when i fixed the problem your program wasnt displaying the correct result. I have looked at project Euler question 8 and have quickly provided this solution. it works and I hope it helps you understand where you went wrong and where to improve on in the future.

```
private static void PE_Problem_8()
    {
        String NumbersArray = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

        long PermanentTotal = 0;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumbersArray.length(); i++) {
                Character firstNum = NumbersArray.charAt(i);
                long TemporaryTotal = Long.parseLong(firstNum.toString());
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= i + 12; j++) {
                    if(j < NumbersArray.length()) {
                        Character secondNum = NumbersArray.charAt(j);
                        if (secondNum.toString().length() > 0) {
                            TemporaryTotal *= Long.parseLong(secondNum.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (TemporaryTotal > PermanentTotal) {
                    PermanentTotal = TemporaryTotal;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("largest product: "+ PermanentTotal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making the code complicated. Let's make it simple and see what happens.

First, let's make a function out of

```
tempx = x;
times = 1;
while (x < (y - 1)){
    System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1])));
    times = times * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x - 1]));
    x++;
    i++;            
}
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.println(
   "X: " + x + "\t Times: " + times + "\t tempx: " + tempx);
x = tempx;
```

So it becomes

```
static int calculateValue(int x, int y, char[] charAr) {
    int times = 1;
    int newx = x;
    while( newx < (y -1) ) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charAr[x-1])));
        times = times * value;
        newx++;
    }
    return times;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String string = ("7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");
    char[] charAr = string.toCharArray();
    int x = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int y = 14;
    int product = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int times = 1;
    int newLargest = 0;
    while (tempx <= 999){
        times = calculateValue(x, y, charAr);
        if(times > newLargest) {
           newLargest = times;
        }
        x++;
        y++;
    }   
}
```

That's a lot better. Now, be a mathematician and start counting at 0.   And let's make a constant for '14', so we can eliminate y. And since we're hunting for that out of bounds, let's ensure that we're not going out of our string length. It might be 999, but why not be safe and use the actual value by using string.length(). And use the string directly instead of that strange array.

```
int calculateValue(int x, String theString) {
    int times = 1;
    int i = x; // traditionally, we use 'i' for loop variables.
    while( i < (x + FOURTEEN) ) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(theString.charAt(i));
        times = times * value;
        i++;
    }
    return times;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String string = ("7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");
    int x = 0;
    int newLargest = 0;
    while (x < string.length()){
        int times = calculateValue(x, string);
        if(times > newLargest) {
           newLargest = times;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

Now, we still haven't fixed the bug, but at least we can reason a bit about it. It's happening because it's running out of bounds.
The maximum size of x is 999. the maximum of 'i' is x+FOURTEEN, or 1013.
and that is longer then our array. So we need to break it off to ensure that doesn't happen.
To do this, we modify calculateValue to stop if it reaches the end of the string.

```
int calculateValue(int x, String theString) {
    int times = 1;
    int i = x; // traditionally, we use 'i' for loop variables.
    while( i < (x + FOURTEEN) && i < theString.length() ) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(theString.charAt(i));
        times = times * value;
        i++;
    }
    return times;
}
```